# How to import functions from different js file in a Vue+webpack+vue-loader project

Tags: javascript, module, webpack, vuejs2, vue-loader

I have `App.vue` which has a template:

```html
    <template>
     <div id="app">
         <login v-if="isTokenAvailable()"></login>
     </div>
    </template>
```

I've declared the `isTokenAvailable` method in the normal way for Vue inside `methods`. It uses a function that I wrote in a separate `js` file:

```js
<script>
    import * as mylib from './mylib';

    export default {
      ....
        methods:{
            isTokenAvailable: () => {
                return mylib.myfunc();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

`mylib` starts like this:

```js
    import models from './model/models'
    import axois from 'axios'

    export default function() {
        // functions and constants
    }
```

When I run the project, I get this below warning:

```js
    export 'myfunc' (imported as 'mylib') was not found in './mylib'
```

I gather I'm not importing or declaring a javascript module correctly... but there seem to be so many ways to do it, added with the complexity of the scoping in Vue, I'm not sure what is the right way to do it?

**Why this isn't a dupe of: [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087)**

That one doesn't seem to fix the problem, specifically in the context of vuejs.

I have tried this:

```js
<script>
    const mylib = require('./mylib');
    ...
</script>
```

With the function modified to: `exports.myfunc = function()`

**Should I have some other dependency for this to work?** Because I get a different error:

```bash
    [Vue warn]: Error in render function:
    TypeError: mylib.myfunc is not a function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: @DanielCooke I understand the above is similar, but it's not the same issue - this is in the context of `Vue`, and I have used `export` as in that answer and it still doesn't work

Comment: You need to read up on Modules in Javascript to solve your problem. You will need to understand what module loaderr you are using. Are you using webpack? SystemJS? You could try const 'myfunc' = require('mylib'); the node.js import syntax.

Comment: @DanielCooke thanks, I'm using webpack. I have tried `const ...` but then I get a different error in the console: mylib.myfunc is not a function

Comment: "mylib.myfunc();" this means that you should return object, but u export function

Comment: @KirillMatrosov sorry I don't understand - can you put into an answer with some more explanation pls?

Comment: I think it is related to a missing source map for the file: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Say I want to import data into a component from `src/mylib.js`:

```
var test = {
  foo () { console.log('foo') },
  bar () { console.log('bar') },
  baz () { console.log('baz') }
}

export default test
```

In my .Vue file I simply imported `test` from `src/mylib.js`:

```
<script> 
  import test from '@/mylib'

  console.log(test.foo())
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Incase anyone is curios to why I wanted to go by this method, I needed a separate batch file to run functions in, now I can easily pass data to mylib and run the desired function with a return statement! Fabulous work.

Comment: Is this supposed to work with vanilla js? I get `Unexpected identifier` for the import part

Answer (score 39):

After a few hours of messing around I eventually got something that works, partially answered in a similar issue here: [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

**BUT** there was an import that was screwing the rest of it up:

### Use require in `.vue` files

```
<script>
  var mylib = require('./mylib');
  export default {
  ....
```

### Exports in `mylib`

```
 exports.myfunc = () => {....}
```

### Avoid `import`

The actual issue in my case (which I didn't think was relevant!) was that `mylib.js` was itself using other dependencies. The resulting error seems to have nothing to do with this, and there was no transpiling error from `webpack` but anyway I had:

```
import models from './model/models'
import axios from 'axios'
```

This works so long as I'm not using `mylib` in a `.vue` component. However as soon as I use `mylib` there, the error described in this issue arises.

I changed to:

```
let models = require('./model/models');
let axios = require('axios');
```

And all works as expected.

Comment: WHYYYYYYY??? This is ridiculous. If I'm using a transpiler such as Babble or Webpack, then whyyy can't we use `import` statements?? I want to pull my hair out...or abandon VueJS, not sure which.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was working on this for 2 hours... your answer saved the day!

Comment: For me this throws *require is not defined*.

Answer (score 10):

I like the answer of Anacrust, though, by the fact "console.log" is executed twice, I would like to do a small update for `src/mylib.js`:

```
let test = {
  foo () { return 'foo' },
  bar () { return 'bar' },
  baz () { return 'baz' }
}

export default test
```

All other code remains the same...

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to organize my vue app code, and came across this question , since I have a lot of logic in my component and can not use other sub-coponents , it makes sense to use many functions in a separate js file and call them in the vue file,  so here is my attempt

1)The Component (.vue file)

```
//MyComponent.vue file
<template>
  <div>
  <div>Hello {{name}}</div>
  <button @click="function_A">Read Name</button>
  <button @click="function_B">Write Name</button>
  <button @click="function_C">Reset</button>
  <div>{{message}}</div>
  </div>
 </template>


<script>
import Mylib from "./Mylib"; // <-- import
export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      name: "Bob",
      message: "click on the buttons"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    function_A() {
      Mylib.myfuncA(this); // <---read data
    },
    function_B() {
      Mylib.myfuncB(this); // <---write data
    },
    function_C() {
      Mylib.myfuncC(this); // <---write data
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

2)The External js file

```
//Mylib.js
let exports = {};

// this (vue instance) is passed as that , so we
// can read and write data from and to it as we please :)
exports.myfuncA = (that) => {
  that.message =
  "you hit ''myfuncA'' function that is located in Mylib.js  and data.name = " +
    that.name;
};

exports.myfuncB = (that) => {
  that.message =
  "you hit ''myfuncB'' function that is located in Mylib.js and now I will change the name to Nassim";
  that.name = "Nassim"; // <-- change name to Nassim
};

exports.myfuncC = (that) => {
  that.message =
  "you hit ''myfuncC'' function that is located in Mylib.js and now I will change the name back to Bob";
  that.name = "Bob"; // <-- change name to Bob
};

export default exports;
```

[image]
3)see it in action :
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-pare-vuw7i?file=/src/components/MyComponent.vue

---

### edit

after getting more experience with Vue , I found out that you could use mixins too to split your code into different files and make it easier to code and maintain see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html